# How can I override get method in django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to do encode the data before saving it to a database table and decode it after reading it from the database table. I wanted to override django get and save methods.

something like:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerFields
    data = models.charField(max_length=25)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        encode_data(self.data)
        super(UserData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super(UserData, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        return decode_data(data)
```

django models have save method and I am able to override it and do what i want. But, they doesnt seem to have a get method which I can override.
How can I achieve this?
I want the data to be decoded on calling UserData.objects.all() or UserData.objects.get() or UserData.objects.filter() or any other such methods available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you do this by overriding `__init__`. But since `__init__` on Django Models does all kind of funky business, it's not recommended to override it. Instead, listen for the `post_init` signal and do your decoding there:

```
def my_decoder(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.decoded_stuff = decode_this(instance.encoded.stuff)

models.signals.post_init.connect(my_decoder, UserData)
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. Django signals documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

Answer (score 6):

Try reading docs about writing custom manager. Remember, you are not calling get on `Model`, but on `Model.objects`, which is a some kind of Manager. Here are the docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/

Comment: Doing it this way would ultimately require you to create a custom QuerySet as well, as the get, filter and all methods on a Manager just pass through to the corresponding methods on the QuerySet returned by the Manager's get_query_set method.

Comment: Apparently it was moved. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/