# Customizing accessing database in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 1.4, python 2.7. I want to encrypt data when it gets inserted into DB and decrypt it when I'm reading it from DB. I can override the Save method of each model to store encrypted data but I don't know what should I do when I want to read this data. I have to handle admin site model and my project's models. Which method should I override?

Comment: i think best way is overwrite django Model with new name like EncryptModel this is for one field example Encrypting Database Data in Django | Tyler Lesmann -> http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2008/dec/19/encrypting-database-data-django/

Comment: But which method in the model should I overwrite? what is the main method that handles reading data from db?

Comment: How can I override get method in django Model? - Stack Overflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492653/how-can-i-override-get-method-in-django-model

Answer (score 1):

The `EncryptedTextField` and `EncryptedCharField` from [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/) seem like the things you're looking for.